# In what ways can I generate EU in feed the beast?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

Feed the beast has many different packs and settings, so for the sake of consistency we shall use the most common combination of core mods, Industrial Craft 2, GregTech, Buildcraft, Forestry, Minefactory Reloaded, and Thermal Expansion. With everything available to you from these mods, what machines generate EU?

Note: I'm not asking for all the different strategies available, rather I'm looking for a small list of the specific machines that generate power.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EU is implemented by Industrialcraft and is generated by so called "generators".

- [Generator](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Generator)
- [Geothermal Generator](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Geothermal_Generator)
- [Thermal Generator](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Thermal_Generator)
- [Semifluid Generator](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Semifluid_Generator)
- [Diesel Generator](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Diesel_Generator)
- [Plasma Generator](http://ftbwiki.org/Plasma_Generator)
- [Water Mill](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Water_Mill)
- [Wind Mill](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Wind_Mill)
- [Solar Panel](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Solar_Panel)
- [Nuclear Reactor](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Nuclear_Reactor)
- [Fusion Reactor](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Fusion_Reactor)
- [Lightning Rod](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Lightning_Rod)
- [Dragon Egg Energy Siphon](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Egg_Energy_Siphon)
- [Magic Energy Converter](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Magic_Energy_Converter)
- [Steam Turbine](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Steam_Turbine)
- [Gas Turbine](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Gas_Turbine)

While there is a simple way to generate MJ from EU by just building a electrical engine and hooking it up to EU by some cables there is no simple solution to convert MJ to EU.

There are ways around this, like a magma crucible (using MJ) can be used to output lava from cobblestone. This lave can be used for your geothermal generators to generate EU.  Cobblestone costs 24000 MJ to concert to a bucket of lava in a magma geothermal generator this yields 20.000 EU, not bad. However if you use netherrack in your magma crucible to convert to lava this only costs 12.000 MJ, this is afaik the most efficient conversion there is.

With this setup you can basically generate/convert to EU with every possible way you generate MJ.

Comment: I'm going to leave this answer un-accepted for a short while (few days or so) as we continue to complete the list, but be assured your gonna get the checkmark. Thanks for all your help! :)

Comment: In the statement after the list, I think you meant to end with "MJ to EU"?